# translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false breaks screen

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have a UIView I created using a XIB file with autolayout constraints.
Everything works great - but when I set that view translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false everything breaks and suddenly I get "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" errors. Why is that?

Comment: Are you doing `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` through code? If yes, paste your code/viewcontroller.

Comment: please post some code